# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::answers()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

```
public function productFaq() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductFaq', 'product_id');
}
public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductFaqAnswers','faq_id');
}

'productFaq' => function($faq){
    $faq->selectRaw('faq_id,user_id,user_name,product_id,product_name, date_of_enquiry,published,question')
        ->with(['answers' => function($answers)
        {
            $answers->select(['faq_id','answer','user_name','date_of_answer'])
            ->where('published','=',1);
        }
    ]);         
 },
```

Comment: Can you show the complete statement?

Comment: Please show your full code, this is unreadable.

Comment: Somewhere in your code, you are doing `->answers()` directly on a builder without using `->get()` or `first()`. Posting related code is the best option to get required answer

Comment: thanks for your concern
issue got resolved

Comment: problem was i forgot to declare below function in the referred model file  :                                                                                                                 public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductFaqAnswers','faq_id');
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call the `with` method on the model, not on the querybuilder so it should be the first statement because when you can `selectRaw` it will returns you a new instance of the querybuilder :

```
$faq->with(['answers' => function($answers) {
    $answers
        ->select(['faq_id','answer','user_name','date_of_answer'])
        ->where('published','=',1);
 }])
 ->selectRaw('faq_id,user_id,user_name,product_id,product_name,
date_of_enquiry,published,question')->get();
```